# Unity android: notifications and performance

Tags: android, performance, unity-game-engine

I recently finished my first android game using Unity 3D and C#.

I noticed that whenever the game is running and my phone gets a notification (I am using a samsung galaxy core phone) the game slows down, skips a couple of frames and continues working. This frame skip breaks the gameplay and I need to address this thing right away.

Any ideas why this is and how I should avoid it? I have been using Time.deltaTime whenever I needed to make position changes and I am using the Unity built in physics engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`FixedUpdate`](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate.html) instead of `Update` when dealing with physics. This way, your physics won't be affected by the performance of the machine.

Comment: But isn't that why you should use Time.deltatime? Isn't that the same thing?

Comment: Hmm if you are dropping some frames and that's affecting your physics it can mean that your physics doesn't rely solely on `Time.deltaTime`, or that `Time.deltaTime` is not reliable in those "out of operating envelope" situations. I don't know, I've seen this `Update` usage in the documentation examples and I've seen people with the same problem as you, and they got it working when changed to `FixedUpdate`.

Comment: And for more info on "it can mean that your physics doesn't rely solely on `Time.deltaTime`" and also to know more about `FixedUpdate` runs with `Update`, take a look at http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/10993/whats-the-difference-between-update-and-fixedupdat.html

Answer (score 0):

This is something I have noticed while developing on lower-end devices. Every time the phone starts doing something else on the background  than running the game e.g fetching emails or updating software it does a FPS hiccup.

I found no solution for this, except for making the game run more optimized overall to minimize the FPS valley.